# Hibernate OO Design Question

Tags: java, hibernate, oop

I'm working on creating a Hibernate query engine that can create dynamic queries.  Thus far I've been using the Criterion API to generate the queries.  I'm having a hard time writing the engine in an OO fashion.  I want to be able to create a new class for each association and have it pass back a fragment of the SQL call.

For example:

A person might own a home, a car, and a boat.

I want the user to be able to search "Return any person that has a blue home and a red boat"
I have a searchTerm Map that looks like:

home.color = blue

boat.color = red

I'd want one singleton, for each criteria (boat,car,home), that I can pass in the entire map and it returns to me a Criteria object that I can use to build up my query.  That's the theory.  The problem I'm having is, in Hibernate, I need to create a criteria or alias to make associations between person and boat/house/car.  In order to do that, I have to pass in the hibernate session.  What I really want is to be able to return a detached-criteria and merge them all together.  But it doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

In summary:
A class that returns a criteria object that makes associations without the session object.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And [`DetachedCriteria`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/criterion/DetachedCriteria.html) doesn't work for you because?

**Update** (based on comment)

> How do I have different objects create
>   different Detached Criteria and merge
>   them all together in one query?

You don't "merge" them. In your example `Person` is the root entity (because you're searching for users; plus it has associations to all other entities like `House`, `Boat`, `Car`). Thus, you'll be initially creating criteria for `Person`:

```
DetachedCriteria personCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Person.class);
```

and then, based on your conditions, create an association when needed:

```
// this assumes that "Boat" is mapped as many-to-one "boat" property on "Person"
DetachedCriteria boatCriteria = personCriteria.createCriteria("boat");
boatCriteria.add(Restriction.eq("color", "red"));

// same for house
DetachedCriteria houseCriteria = personCriteria.createCriteria("house");
houseCriteria.add(Restriction.eq("color", "blue"));

// when you're all done you search based on "personCriteria"
personCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```

---

On a side note, you might want to take a look at [Hibernate Generic DAO](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) project, particularly its [Search](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/wiki/Search) component which is basically Criteria API done right :-)

Comment: But how do I have different objects create different Detached Criteria and merge them all together in one query?